# Crash in my app starting activity

Tags: java, android

Here I'm trying to create Login email and password functions.
the app works fine for this code of yours below:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mRegButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        mRegButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_reg_btn);
        mRegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent regIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(regIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when i add the code below to make the login button work, the app crashes:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mRegButton;
    private Button mLoginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        mRegButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_reg_btn);
        mRegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent regIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(regIntent);
            }
        });

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });
        }
}
```

please help. i have been wasting almost 4 hour trying to figure what is happening, but failed to get the problem solved.

Comment: And where's your exception and your stacktrace?

Comment: @f1sh well, I'm not sure what u r talking about. it would be gr8 if u temme more about it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Everyone will always tell you, for this kind of problems you have 2 choices:

`read your stack trace and figure out the problem yourself`

or

`provide your stack trace`

In both situations you need to be aware of the problem to solve it.
Since you're new to programming here, have a look at these topics, they will help you greatly solving this problem and many more problems you will encounter in the future:

[How to solve application crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

[What is stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check Login.Class logcat traces what is error. Since, issue is in the login class so it's unable to Launch startActivity intent when you click on LoginButton.